# Should I update the question title to a better one, which contains terms not known to OP?

Tags: discussion, title

I'm talking specifically about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22174022/1679863). Currently the title is not very clear as to what is being is asked. Would it be better to change the title to:

> Why giving explicit type arguments to non-generic method or constructor works?

This is because, the question will more likely be searched through google easily with that title.

My concern is, the updated title will then show that OP knows about *explicit type arguments*, and also knows how it works with generic method, which is not the case when one goes through the question body.

Should I do such updates?

Comment: Is this a rarely used feature in Java? I am asking because I have never seen this before. If this is an obscure feature, then I really doubt the terminology is widely known. IMHO, it might be better to change it to "Why does new <Type>ArrayList() gives warning while new ArrayList<Type>() does not?"

Comment: @nhahtdh No, [the terminology is well known](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+generics+explicit+type+argument&rlz=2C1CHWA_enIN0536IN0536&oq=java+generics+explicit+type+argument&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4275j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: The [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page would prompt me to say that if a change _improves_ the post, it is worth doing.  The goal is to help future visitors as well.  If you think that an existing title is vague enough, change it to something that isn't perhaps as vague!

Comment: @devnull Yes we can edit the question to improve it, unless it changes the meaning, or perhaps adds something new that arises from the answers. That is what the case is here.